# ServiceNow dot walking in tree picker

Tags: servicenow

How do I accomplish what is described in this article?

[Dot walking in tree picker](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-platform-user-interface/page/use/navigation/concept/c_DotWalkingInATreePicker.html)

How do I get a "glide list field to show the select fields icon," as described in the second line of the article?

I have tried creating a reference and list fields, each with the tree_picker=true attribute set, and I have not been able to generate this interface that allows me to create a dot-walked variable (as shown in the article) such as "assigned_to.manager", the example the article uses.

Comment: We're going to need more information about what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "reference and list fields"? You refer to fields, but you also refer to "dot-walked variables". Is this on a catalog item, or a table? How about a screenshot? What attributes have you added, EXACTLY? Please include more info if you expect people to be able to help you.

Comment: Tim, Sunil knew what was up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Attributes set `allow_references=true`

I hope you are already using Column type as field name.
Add the above property and you will be able to dot walk on all reference fields.